# Anyone using Full SSL for CloudFlare => GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, cloudflare

I know CloudFlare's web site says you have to use "Flexible SSL" (i.e., half SSL) with GAE, but one of their support techs I spoke to is not sure whether that statement still applies. Before I sign up, can anyone state whether they are using Full encrypted SSL with CloudFlare to a GAE app using their *.appspot.com host name?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the actual server has SSL for your site, then Flexible is the correct option. Full SSL only applies when you have an actual SSL cert on your server directly.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I spoke more with that support tech, and he noted that CloudFlare leaves the host header of the proxied request to GAE with the same hostname that the client used. That means CloudFlare will not set the host header to the <appid>.appspot.com name. So Full SSL will definitely not work for https://<appid>.appspot.com. If CloudFlare supports SNI SSL to GAE, then it should work with the custom domain name, as you mention. But I have not tested that scenario. I was only interested in using appspot.com.